# Print squares of odds up to N, then squares of evens, using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have to print the squares of n using recursion, and I have to print first the odd numbers squared in descending order, followed by the even numbers squared in ascending order.

The odd numbers sorted code is working while my even numbers sorted code is not.

I have divided the problem into two methods then joined it into one, the first method will print out the squared odd numbers in descending order, then the second "should" print out the squared even numbers in ascending order:

Here you  go:

```
public static String printSquares(int n) {
    // Prints out the squares to n
    // Odd numbers first in descending order
    // Even numbers next in ascending order
    return oddsSquared(n) + evensSquared("", n);
}

public static String evensSquared(String s, int n) {
    // I have no idea why this is not working
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Argument");
    }

    if (n == 2) {
        return 2*2 +" "+ s;
    } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        s = n * n +" "+ s;
        return s + evensSquared(s, n--);
    } else {
        return evensSquared(s, n--);
    }
}

public static String oddsSquared(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Argument");
    }

    if (n == 1) {
        return 1 + "";
    } else if (n % 2 != 0) {
        return n * n + " " + oddsSquared(n - 1);
    } else {
        return oddsSquared(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the actual question, and any explanation. You can't just offload code like that, most people won't be running it anyway.

Comment: Could you add an example of what inputs are, what expected outputs are and what are your outputs ?

Comment: Is it like `printSquares(5)` should return `25, 9, 1, 16, 4`?

Comment: What is the output of your algorithm ? Did you try with some sample results like 4 or 5 ? You should put loggers to see how is your code going, or even a debugger if you are using an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you use `n--`

In your code for odd number, you call your function inside your function using `n-1` which actually return `n-1` (pretty obvious I know). So for example if `n=5` then `n-1` return `4`.

But in your code for even numbers you call your function inside your function using `n--` that does not return `n-1` but `n`. (That's where it's tricky). `n--` returns `n` then apply minus 1. So if you have `n=5` then `n--` will return 5.

You can use `--n` that will first apply minus 1 to `n` before returning it, or you can use `n-1` that is not confusing, so that avoid mistakes.

---

Your second problem is here :

```
s = n * n +" "+ s;
return s + evensSquared(s, n--);
```

You are adding s two times, one time at the end and one time at the beginning. You should remove the second one.

```
s = n * n +" "+ s;
return evensSquared(s, n--);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print in ascending order then your should call the rescursion first and should reach to the lowest number first.

Updated the code there was some mistake in one condition

```
 public static String evensSquared(String s, int n) {
    // I have no idea why this is not working
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Argument");
    }

    if (n == 2) {
        return "4";
    } else if (n % 2 == 0) {

        return  evensSquared(s, n-1)+" "+n*n;
    } else {
        return evensSquared(s, n-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that we're asked for two groups in opposite ordering. In recursion, we can associate descending with prepending and ascending with appending. Watch (JavaScript code):

```js
// first the odd numbers squared in
// descending order, followed by the
// even numbers squared in ascending order

function f(n){
  if (n == 1)
    return '1';
   
  if (n & 1)
    return n*n + ' ' + f(n - 1);

  return f(n - 1) + ' ' + n*n;
}

console.log(f(8));
```

Comment: Why answer with javascript when we are talking about Java ?

Comment: @vincrichaud because the function is simple enough to convert, it's easy to demonstrate right on the Stack Overflow web page, I was using a phone so I did not have access to an IDE, and I'm not versed in Java so I would have to spend some time experimenting to make sure the code was ok :)